# How can I access the number of questions asked on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

Is there a Stackoverflow web service available to grab the amount of question asked?

I dont want to srape the page as this probably is forbidden.

I want to write a program to simple monitor the count so i can be the 3 millionth question!

What an honor that would be :)

Comment: Questions about the site (and/or site complex) should be on the meta site. What an honor to spam the system and steal the rightful question out from a legitimate 3 millionth poster's nose...

Comment: You assume that my question is not worthy?

Comment: Why was this migrated to meta? It's obviously a programming question!

Comment: Fine, i'll have to settle for 3,000,001

Comment: No one will even know yours is the 3,000,000th question. The number in the URL uses a *post* ID number which just recently passed 10,000,000.

Comment: Can you please, in the future, capitalize `I`? When you ask questions here, or on SO, it's like going to a formal dinner. Not proofing your questions is like showing up in shorts that have a broken fly, with no underwear.

Comment: @larsmans its like a service request not a programing question.

Comment: Tim, ill try and be more careful next time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. See the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).